# How to use Python any() function on a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

I have a nested dictionary like so:

```
data = { "m" : [{ "id" : "1", "reg": [{ "reg_id" : "1", "status" : "B" }, { "reg_id" : "2", "status" : "C" }]}]
```

and I want to find out if any of the values paired with the key "status" are equal to "A". How would I do this? This code is returning "True" when it should be "False":

```
any((reg["status"] == "A" for reg in m["reg"])
        for m in data["m"])
```

Comment: note that `data["meters"]` is a list so `meter["registers"]` produces an error

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes is better to remove some *nestedness*:

```
data = {"meters": [{"id": "1", "registers": [{"reg_id": "1", "status": "B"}, {"reg_id": "2", "status": "C"}]}]}

meters = data["meters"]
result = any(xds["status"] == "A" for ds in meters for xds in ds["registers"])
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
False
```

A more general solution, for all values of the top dictionary, is:

```
result = any(xds["status"] == "A" for meters in data.values() for ds in meters for xds in ds["registers"])
```

Comment: Should the output not be False? As there is no "status"=="A"

Comment: It was a typo, if you run the code its going to output false. Now its fixed

Answer (score 0):

From this (note the missing `}` at the end)

```py
data = { "meters" : [{ "id" : "1", "registers": [{ "reg_id" : "1", "status" : "B" }, { "reg_id" : "2", "status" : "C" }]}]}
```

you can get the `registers`

```py
>>> regs = data["meters"][0]["registers"]
>>> regs
[{'reg_id': '1', 'status': 'B'}, {'reg_id': '2', 'status': 'C'}]
```

and then the task is not that complicated

```py
>>> any(reg["status"] == "A" for reg in regs)
False
>>> any(reg["status"] == "B" for reg in regs)
True
```